# PHP remove Special Chars ” `

Tags: php, regex

want to remove special characters like

`<div><a href="http//news.yahoo.com/small-business-internet-marketing-survey-over-40-crying-140118854.html"><font size="3" color="Blue">Small Business Internet Marketing Survey Over 40% Crying For Help</font></a><br><font size="2" color="black">A new survey of small businessâ€s internet marketing practices`

businessâ€s  also tm reg i need to do 2 things

- Remove ” ` and maintain formatting(html tags) and keep spaces as well
- Is there any way i can show special characters like ” ` in another variable

Comment: Technically not the answer to your problem, but have you considered converting the text encoding so that the 'wrong' characters display correctly?

Comment: can you let me how to do that? new to php world

Comment: You can't arbitrarily remove quote marks, because they are part of your valid HTML. If this is about making it safe for saving to a database, then you should be escaping the unwanted characters, not removing them.

Comment: I need to keep spaces and html tags... and delete special chars like ” (note they arent double quotes) and trademark and other special characters

Comment: One of the big problems here is that we are working with a Type 1 (context sensitive) language (regex) and trying to do type 2 (context free) operations.  Since all preservation has to happen in HTML tags, BUT everything else should be escaped properly, you would have to make a PDA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) to analyze that. ... ... .. I could also be wrong and largely be overestimating the difficulty of what your asking :)

Comment: All i want is t remove Trademark and ` ” (not simple double quotes) isnt this something PHP should take care of... i have this string and need to strp these special chars

Comment: @chirag: First, read this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. Then, what I recommend is to use Unicode (UTF-8, ideally) for everything under your control: the database connection ('SET NAMES UTF8' in mysql), PHP's internal processing and input/output encodings (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-output.php etc.). For data you receive that isn't UTF-8, use this one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php.

Comment: Thanks, I read through and you guided me all the way to home run :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace(array('"', '`'), array('&quot;', '&#96;'), $text);
```

Comment: hmmm... it depends on why he wants to remove them. If he's outputting to the browser then yes (although this will break his HTML), but if its because he wants to save to a database then he needs to quite different escaping.

Comment: I need to keep spaces and html tags... and delete special chars like ” (note they arent double quotes) and trademark and other special characters
i need to output to browser so i need html tags but trademark and other symbols are annoying for eg

want to remove special characters like
businessâ€s

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP str_replace must work... http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code that i use to REMOVE ALL SPECIAL CHARACTERS.  This includes anything that is not an alphanumeric character (a-Z and 0-9) and white space.

```
function removeAllSpecialCharacters($string) {
    return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]/", "", $string);
}
```

I do not know if that answers your question.  Please give me feedback.

Comment: i want to keep space and html tags and remove special chars like `  ”  or  trademark or registerd